# Sender Circuit for Ultrasound

Tags: mosfet, mosfet-driver, ultrasound, powermosfet

I'm building this Instructables project: [Body-ultrasound Sonography With Arduino](https://www.instructables.com/Body-ultrasound-Sonography-With-Arduino/), which is using ultrasound to see inside the body. However I'm having some issues with the sender circuit, shown below:

[image: 1]

The Arduino is being used to trigger the SN74121 and so a short 100-200ns should e created and sent to the ICL7667. From this a switching pulse between 0-9V should be generated to drive the power mosfet, IRL620.

However, my issue is the ICL7667. At pin 6 my output is 0v and doesn't change. At pin 2 and 4 the voltage measures to be 3.88V. Therefore the power mosfet gate isn't being turned ON. Not sure what I'm doing wrong. I'm using the [IC7667](https://uk.rs-online.com/web/p/gate-drivers/1900927/).

I'm also using two DC power bench supplies that are set to 9V/1A and are connected together to give +9V/GND/-9V.

Full circuit diagram : [image: 2]

Circuit Wirings, the blue cable going to SN74121 is Arduino trigger. [image: 3]

DC bench power supply, the current being drawn from the circuit: [image: 4]

Arduino Code:

```
#define pin_output 5
#define pin_input_magnification 4
#define pin_input_sleep 3

unsigned long start_time;
unsigned long stop_time;
unsigned int values[600];    // Array with the read voltage values


int i, j;
int Trigger_time;    // Duration of the trigger pulse

// =========================
// ========= SETUP =========
// =========================

void setup()
   {
    Serial.begin(115200);  
    
    REG_ADC_MR = 0x10380080;              // change from 10380200 to 10380080, 1 is the PREESCALER and 8 means FREERUN
    ADC -> ADC_CHER = 0x03;               // enable ADC on pin A7
    
    pinMode(pin_output, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(pin_input_magnification, INPUT);    // Switch-input for magnification
    pinMode(pin_input_sleep, INPUT);            // Switch-input for sleep-mode   
    digitalWrite(pin_output, LOW); 
 
    Trigger_time = 1;                     //Duration of the trigger pulse

// ========================
// ========= LOOP =========
// ========================


void loop()
   {
    for (j = 0; j < 18; j++)   // Display of 18 scans side by side in the x-direction
       {   
        // Output of the trigger signal
        // ==========================
    
        digitalWrite(pin_output,HIGH);
        //delayMicroseconds(Trigger_time);
        digitalWrite(pin_output,LOW);
        


        // Reading in the US reflections
        // ===========================

        start_time = micros();
        
        if (digitalRead(pin_input_magnification) == LOW)   // without time extension reading of 300 values; recorded time span = 120 µsec
           {
            for(i = 0; i < 300; i++)
               {
                while((ADC->ADC_ISR & 0x03)==0);  // wait for conversion
        
                values[i] = ADC->ADC_CDR[0];      //get values

                //delayMicroseconds(1);
               }
           }
        else       //reading of 600 values ​​with time extension; recorded time span = 240 µsec
           {
            for(i = 0; i < 600; i++)
               {
                while((ADC->ADC_ISR & 0x03)==0);  // wait for conversion
        
                values[i] = ADC->ADC_CDR[0];      //get values

                //delayMicroseconds(1);
               }
            
           }
    
        //delayMicroseconds(100);
        //delay(5);
    
        
        stop_time = micros();

        Serial.print("Total time for 300 values: ");
        Serial.print(stop_time-start_time);
        Serial.println(" microseconds");
        Serial.print("Average time in microseconds per conversion: ");
        Serial.println((float)(stop_time-start_time)/300);
        
        
        
        Serial.println("Values: ");
        
        for(i = 0;i < 600; i++)
           {
            Serial.println(values[i]);
           }
        

        // Interrogate the pause button
        // =====================
        
        if (digitalRead(pin_input_sleep) == HIGH)
           {

            while(digitalRead(pin_input_sleep) == HIGH)
               {
                // sleeping
               }
           }
             
        delay(1000);    
       }
      
   }
```

Comment: Where are you connecting the minus 9 volts?

Comment: Hi @Andyaka, the -9V is used in the receiver + peak detector circuit to power the op-amps. I'll attach the full circuit diagram.

Comment: Pin 6 is VDD on the 7667, did you mean pin 5 and 7?

Comment: Hi! @OskarSkog yes, apologies I meant pins 5 and 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to resolve the issue with not knowing if Arduino was triggering the 74121 or not. I made a separate circuit with just the 74121 and larger RC components so the pulse width would be longer. With the new RC components I calculated the new pulse width to be 1.3 seconds. I timed the LED going from LOW-HIGH and I got 1.27 seconds. Therefore Arduino does trigger the monostable but it's just really hard to see with the smaller RC components. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the Arduino output is not triggering the 74121 monostable on the B input p5 positive edge >2V.

Once you get the arduino output toggling between 0 & 1 and the 74141 output is not changing, that could mean the pulse width is too small.  Putting your ungrounded finger across the radial cap or changing it to a bigger one ought to make visible Vavg readings on the output on 74141 p1 and also the 7661 and the FET Vdc avg.

Comment: Yes, I thought this too but I was using the code from the Instructables site.

Comment: Did you verify pulses?

Comment: I only have a multimeter, therefore can't look 'inside' the circuit. But when I print the trigger to serial it outputs 1 each time.

Comment: If the pulses exist then Qbar will lower voltage from stuck high pin 2 at 3.88V when you connect the blue wire

Comment: Okay, I was thinking that since the IC7667 is an inverting mosfet, if there's a HIGH at the input pins I'll get 0V on the output pins. Also 74121, needs a positive pulse to be triggered, therefore the output changes from HIGH to LOW in a very short time (100-200ns). Therefore, ICL7667 only goes high for 100-200ns therefore the reason I think I'm not seeing the switching voltage is because it happens too fast for the multimeter to see.

Comment: For DC the average voltage changes with duty cycle or repetition rate for a fixed  pulse.  A low pass filter to DVM can see this if you are worried

Comment: I connected the Arduino trigger cable and measured the voltage of pin 2 of the ICL7667 and it still remains at 3.88V. I've attached the Arduino code.

Comment: Did you try compiling it yet?

Comment: yes, I've verified and uploaded it and everything was fine with no errors. However, the voltage at pin 2 still remains above 2V

Comment: I'm getting 1.45V now on pin 5 of the 74121. However, pin 1 or Q bar is 3.90V.